# Regex - three same characters/digits in a string followed by each other

Tags: javascript, regex

My current regex for finding three of a same characters/digits in string length of 5 is an array:

```
threes: [/2{3}/, /3{3}/, /4{3}/, /5{3}/, /6{3}/, /7{3}/, /8{3}/, /9{3}/, /T{3}/, /J{3}/, /Q{3}/, /K{3}/, /A{3}/]
```

so it validates if in a string for example: `2QQQK` - it matches regex `/Q{3}/` and 333TQ matches regex /3{3}/

I assume there must be option to write it shorter inside one regex not check using multiple.

Comment: `/([2-9TJQKA])\1\1/`

Comment: Strange I can't easily find a duplicate of this, it's a basic regex question.. @WiktorStribiżew maybe you know one? Or else you should probably add a short answer with an explanation for the OP tu understand what's `\1`

Comment: @Kaddath I already closed it with the relevant post. It is not that basic, but is a well-known problem already widely covered on SO.

Comment: Wiktor - many thanks for soluton and reply. But I agree with Kaddath - I searched quiet intensely and did not find solution - only when you linked it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew we must have crossed the sreams while commenting ;) have a good day you regex Master!

Comment: @RobertAndrosz I suggest Google search, it usually yields more relevant searches than the SO search system (disclaimer: I do not work for Google :)).